# Angular creates scrollbar when clicking on <a> link, but it shouldn't?

Tags: javascript, angular, navigation, scrollbar, angular2-routing

I created a side navigation bar with mat-nav-list and link/anchor tags in NavigationComponent.
There is 3 nav link: Home, Contact, Other. Only the Home has routeLink (the others only href="#"), and every time I click in Home, the site acts like it loaded so much content it had to make changes in height, but there is no content loading (which is fine), but still the scrollbar appaer for like 1 sec, and then dissappears. If I click one of these buttons fast enough, the scrollbar gets smaller and smaller, and after 1 sec it dissapears.
Do you know what causes this bug?

Edit: 
Code:

AppComponent (root):

```
<app-header class="center_component header"></app-header>
<app-navigation-menu></app-navigation-menu>
<div class="home_content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer class="center_component"></app-footer>
```

Navigation menu:

```
<mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/home']" 
            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Home </a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#" 
            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Projects </a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#" 
            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Contact </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeContentComponent } from './home-content/home-content.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeContentComponent }/*,
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}*/
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Instead of describing your code, why don't you post it? :)

Comment: You're right, I edited.

Comment: I think I found the problem. If I take out the mat-list-item property from anchor/link tags, then the behavior is fine.
Looks like mat-list-item flag makes the anchor tags behave strange, but I need them to be below each other (side nav).